# Is "cudaMallocManaged" slower than "cudaMalloc"?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, hpc

I downloaded CUDA 6.0 RC and tested the new unified memory by using "cudaMallocManaged" in my application.However, I found this kernel is slowed down.

Using [cudaMalloc](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gc63ffd93e344b939d6399199d8b12fef.html) followed by [cudaMemcpy](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741.html#g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741) is faster (~0.56), compared to cudaMallocManaged (~0.63).Is this expected?

One of the [website](http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/Releases/NVIDIA-Dramatically-Simplifies-Parallel-Programming-With-CUDA-6-a62.aspx) claims that cudaMallocManged is for "faster prototyping of cuda kernel", so I was wondering which is a better option for application in terms of performance?

Thanks.

Comment: If the host memory is *pinned*, yes it is expected to be faster than managed memory.

Comment: but I am not using any _pinned_ memory.

Comment: How do you allocate host memory ?

Comment: I have copied the kernel calling part and allocation part above for refrence.

Comment: Thanks, but how is allocated the host memory (`*.data`) ?

Comment: List.data, MatchLeft.data etc, is a custom data type (OpenCV::Mat to be specific) on the host memory and it is not pinned.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`cudaMallocManaged()` is *not* about speeding up your application (with a few exceptions or corner cases, some are suggested below).

Today's implementation of Unified Memory and `cudaMallocManaged` will **not be faster** than intelligently written code written by a proficient CUDA programmer, to do the same thing.  The machine (cuda runtime) is not smarter than you are as a programmer.  `cudaMallocManaged` does not magically make the PCIE bus or general machine architectural limitations disappear.

Fast prototyping refers to the time it takes you to write the code, not the speed of the code.

`cudaMallocManaged` may be of interest to a proficient cuda programmer in the following situations:

1. You're interested in quickly getting a prototype together -i.e. you don't care about the last ounce of performance.
2. You are dealing with a complicated data structure which you use infrequently (e.g. a doubly linked list) which would otherwise be a chore to port to CUDA (since deep copies using ordinary CUDA code tend to be a chore).  It's necessary for your application to work, but not part of the performance path.
3. You would ordinarily use zero-copy.  There may be situations where using `cudaMallocManaged` could be faster than a naive or inefficient zero-copy approach.
4. You are working on [a Jetson device](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-for-tegra-appnote/index.html).

`cudaMallocManaged` may be of interest to a *non-proficient* CUDA programmer in that it allows you to get your feet wet with CUDA along a possibly simpler learning curve.  (However, note that naive usage of `cudaMallocManaged` may result in a CUDA kernels running slower than expected, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782746/why-is-nvidia-pascal-gpus-slow-on-running-cuda-kernels-when-using-cudamallocmana/40011988#40011988) and [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/maximizing-unified-memory-performance-cuda/).)

Although Maxwell is mentioned in the comments, CUDA UM will offer major new features with the Pascal generation of GPUs, in some settings, for some GPUs.  In particular, Unified Memory in these settings will no longer be limited to the available GPU device memory, and the memory handling granularity will drop to the page level even when the kernel is running.  You can read more about it [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/inside-pascal/).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply. I guess in my case cudamalloc is more suited. Many Thanks....

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the Maxwell architecture should provide HW support for unified memory so `cudaMallocManaged()` could provide better performance on that architecture.

Comment: My statements are mostly intended to reflect what Unified Memory will do *today*. It's reasonable to assume that future evolutions of UM will: **1.** take advantage of newer HW architectures, both on the GPU and on the host, and **2.**  further blur the line between what can or should be handled by the proficient CUDA programmer, and what can or should be left to the machine (CUDA runtime) to accomplish.

Comment: Agreed 100%. Was just making a note since your answer didn't mention Maxwell.