# Why is NVIDIA Pascal GPUs slow on running CUDA Kernels when using cudaMallocManaged

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, nvcc

I was testing the new CUDA 8 along with the Pascal Titan X GPU and is expecting speed up for my code but for some reason it ends up being slower. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is the minimum code that can reproduce the result:

**CUDASample.cuh**

```
class CUDASample{
 public:
  void AddOneToVector(std::vector<int> &in);
};
```

**CUDASample.cu**

```
__global__ static void CUDAKernelAddOneToVector(int *data)
{
  const int x  = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  const int y  = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  const int mx = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

  data[y * mx + x] = data[y * mx + x] + 1.0f;
}

void CUDASample::AddOneToVector(std::vector<int> &in){
  int *data;
  cudaMallocManaged(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&data),
                    in.size() * sizeof(int),
                    cudaMemAttachGlobal);

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); i++){
    data[i] = in.at(i);
  }

  dim3 blks(in.size()/(16*32),1);
  dim3 threads(32, 16);

  CUDAKernelAddOneToVector<<<blks, threads>>>(data);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); i++){
    in.at(i) = data[i];
  }

  cudaFree(data);
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
std::vector<int> v;

for (int i = 0; i < 8192000; i++){
  v.push_back(i);
}

CUDASample cudasample;

cudasample.AddOneToVector(v);
```

The only difference is the NVCC flag, which for the Pascal Titan X is:

```
-gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61-std=c++11;
```

and for the old Maxwell Titan X is:

```
-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52-std=c++11;
```

EDIT: Here are the results for running NVIDIA Visual Profiling.

For the old Maxwell Titan, the time for memory transfer is around 205 ms, and the kernel launch is around 268 us. 
[image]

For the Pascal Titan, the time for memory transfer is around 202 ms, and the kernel launch is around an insanely long 8343 us, which makes me believe something is wrong.
[image]

I further isolate the problem by replacing cudaMallocManaged into good old cudaMalloc and did some profiling and observe some interesting result.

CUDASample.cu

```
__global__ static void CUDAKernelAddOneToVector(int *data)
{
  const int x  = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  const int y  = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  const int mx = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

  data[y * mx + x] = data[y * mx + x] + 1.0f;
}

void CUDASample::AddOneToVector(std::vector<int> &in){
  int *data;
  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&data), in.size() * sizeof(int));
  cudaMemcpy(reinterpret_cast<void*>(data),reinterpret_cast<void*>(in.data()), 
             in.size() * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  dim3 blks(in.size()/(16*32),1);
  dim3 threads(32, 16);

  CUDAKernelAddOneToVector<<<blks, threads>>>(data);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  cudaMemcpy(reinterpret_cast<void*>(in.data()),reinterpret_cast<void*>(data), 
             in.size() * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaFree(data);
}
```

For the old Maxwell Titan, the time for memory transfer is around 5 ms both ways, and the kernel launch is around 264 us. 
[image]

For the Pascal Titan, the time for memory transfer is around 5 ms both ways, and the kernel launch is around 194 us, which actually results in the performance increase I am hoping to see...
[image]

Why is Pascal GPU so slow on running CUDA kernels when cudaMallocManaged is used? It will be a travesty if I have to revert all my existing code that uses cudaMallocManaged into cudaMalloc. This experiment also shows that the memory transfer time using cudaMallocManaged is a lot slower than using cudaMalloc, which also feels like something is wrong. If using this  results in a slow run time even the code is easier, this should be unacceptable because the whole purpose of using CUDA instead of plain C++ is to speed things up. What am I doing wrong and why am I observing this kind of result?

Comment: 1. vector add isn't a particularly interesting test for GPU speed.  2. It's impossible to tell what you are timing exactly, or how.  3. There's no way a vector add kernel on 4096 elements should take ~70ms on *any* GPU.  70us is more plausible.  This is such a tiny little problem that you are almost certainly measuring some kind of overhead, as opposed to actual GPU compute performance

Comment: Increase the problem size to 100M elements.   Modify your code to call your kernel twice in a row.  Then run your code using `nvprof`.  The 2nd invocation of your kernel should run faster on the newer Titan X.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I updated with results from nvvp. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what driver version do you have?

Comment: @harrism The latest 367.44

Comment: Are both the Maxwell and the Pascal in the same system? If so, can you try running wth the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES end variable set to only one of the GPU IDs at a time? Could help shake out the problem.

Comment: @harrism It's the same computer and both GPU weren't connected to the PC at the same time. I only put in one to test. Afterwards I turn the power off and swap them and turn power back on and test again.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Under CUDA 8 with Pascal GPUs, managed memory data migration under a unified memory (UM) regime will generally occur differently than on previous architectures, and you are experiencing the effects of this.  (Also see note at the end about CUDA 9 updated behavior for windows.)

With previous architectures (e.g. Maxwell), managed allocations used by a particular kernel call will be migrated all at once, upon launch of the kernel, approximately as if you called `cudaMemcpy` to move the data yourself.

With CUDA 8 and Pascal GPUs, data migration occurs via demand-paging.  At kernel launch, by default, no data is explicitly migrated to the device(*).   When the GPU device code attempts to access data in a particular page that is not resident in GPU memory, a page fault will occur.  The net effect of this page fault is to:

1. Cause the GPU kernel code (the thread or threads that accessed the page) to stall (until step 2 is complete)
2. Cause that page of memory to be migrated from the CPU to the GPU

This process will be repeated as necessary, as GPU code touches various pages of data. The sequence of operations involved in step 2 above involves some *latency* as the page fault is processed, in addition to the time spent to actually move the data.  Since this process will move data a page at a time, it may be signficantly less efficient than moving all the data at once, either using `cudaMemcpy` or else via the pre-Pascal UM arrangement that caused all data to be moved at kernel launch (whether it was needed or not, and regardless of when the kernel code actually needed it).

Both approaches have their pros and cons, and I don't wish to debate the merits or various opinions or viewpoints.  The demand-paging process enables a great many important features and capabilities for Pascal GPUs.

This particular code example, however, does not benefit.  This was anticipated, and so the recommended use to bring the behavior in line with previous (e.g. maxwell) behavior/performance is to precede the kernel launch with a [`cudaMemPrefetchAsync()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8dc9199943d421bc8bc7f473df12e42) call.

You would use the CUDA stream semantics to force this call to complete prior to the kernel launch (if the kernel launch does not specify a stream, you can pass NULL for the stream parameter, to select the default stream).  I believe the other parameters for this function call are pretty self-explanatory.

With this function call before your kernel call, covering the data in question, you should not observe any page-faulting in the Pascal case, and the profile behavior should be similar to the Maxwell case.

As I mentioned in the comments, if you had created a test case that involved two kernel calls in sequence, you would have observed that the 2nd call runs at approximately full speed even in the Pascal case, since all of the data has already been migrated to the GPU side through the first kernel execution.  Therefore, the use of this prefetch function should not be considered mandatory or automatic, but should be used thoughtfully.  There are situations where the GPU may be able to hide the latency of page-faulting to some degree, and obviously data already resident on the GPU does not need to be prefetched.

Note that the "stall" referred to in step 1 above is possibly misleading.  A memory access by itself does not trigger a stall.  But if the data requested is actually needed for an operation, e.g. a multiply, then the warp will stall at the multiply operation, until the necessary data becomes available.  A related point, then, is that demand-paging of data from host to device in this fashion is just another "latency" that the GPU can possibly hide in it's latency-hiding architecture, if there is sufficient other available "work" to attend to.

As an additional note, in CUDA 9, the demand-paging regime for pascal and beyond is only available on linux; the previous support for Windows advertised in CUDA 8 has been dropped.  See [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-requirements).  On windows, even for Pascal devices and beyond, as of CUDA 9, the UM regime is the same as maxwell and prior devices; data is migrated to the GPU en-masse, at kernel launch.

(*) The assumption here is that data is "resident" on the host, i.e. already "touched" or initialized in CPU code, after the managed allocation call.  The managed allocation itself creates data pages associated with the device, and when CPU code "touches" these pages, the CUDA runtime will demand-page the necessary pages to be resident in host memory, so that the CPU can use them.  If you perform an allocation but never "touch" the data in CPU code (an odd situation, probably) then it will actually already be "resident" in device memory when the kernel runs, and the observed behavior will be different.  But that is not the case in view for this particular example/question.

Additional information is available in [this](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/maximizing-unified-memory-performance-cuda/) blog article.

Comment: Using cudaMemPrefetchAsync solves it for me. Also the difference between the Pascal and Maxwell is really nicely explained!

Comment: @user3667089 No kidding. This answer is brilliant. I doubt it could be explained more concisely and effectively by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this in three programms on a 1060 and a 1080. As example i use a voulme render with procedural transferfunction which was nearly interactive real time on a 960 but on a 1080 is a slight show. All data are stored in read only textures and only my transferfunctions are in Managed Memory. In difference to my other code the volume render runs especially slow, this is becaus in differece to my other code my transferfunctions are passed from the kernel to other device methods.

I belive that it is not only the calling of kernels with cudaMallocManaged data. My expierence go to that every call of a kernel or device methode has this behavior and the effect adds up. Also the basis of the volume render is in parts the provided CudaSample without Managed Memory, which runs as expected on Maxwell an pascal GPUs (1080, 1060,980Ti,980,960).

I just yesterday found this bug, because we changed all of oure reaserch systems to pascal. I will profile my software in the next days on a 980 in comapre to a 1080. I'm not yet sure if i should report a bug in the NVIDIA developer zone.

Comment: If this is not a bug from NVIDIA, let me know if you managed to find a way to solve this. I am still stuck on using the maxwell GPUs because I don't want to change all my code from cudaMallocManaged to cudaMalloc

Answer (score -2):

it is a BUG of NVIDIA on Windows Systems witch occurs with PASCAL architecture.

I know this since a few days, but could not write it here because i was on vacation without internet connection.

For details see the comments of: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/ 
where Mark Harris from NVIDIA confirms the Bug. It should be corrected with CUDA 9. He also tells that it should be communicated to Microsoft to help the caus. But i don't found a suitable Microsoft Bug Report Page till now.

Comment: You are mixing up two different things.  The bug you are referring to is an implementation issue of managed memory on Windows WDDM.  It is not the same as the issue OP reported, and OP has already confirmed that the accepted answer fixes the issue observed.  In fact, CUDA 9 has actually dropped support for demand-paging on windows, and the windows behavior for UM reverts to the pre-pascal regime (no demand-paging), even for pascal devices and beyond.  See [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-requirements).