# cudaMemPrefetchAsync() returns cudaErrorInvalidDevice - why?

Tags: debugging, cuda

Whenever I call `cudaMemPrefetchAsync()` it returns the error code `cudaErrorInvalidDevice`. I am sure that I pass right device id (I have only one CUDA-capable GPU in my laptop under `id == 0`).

I believe that code sample posted below is error-free, but at line `52` (call to `cudaMemPrefetchAsync()`) I keep getting this error.

---

### I tried:

1. Clean driver installation. (Latest version)
2. I check Google for an answer, but I could not find any. (I managed only to find [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/981147/cuda-programming-and-performance/cudamemprefetchasync-returns-cudaerrorinvaliddevice/))

(I haven't idea for anything else)

---

### System Spec:

**OS:** Microsoft windows 8.1 x64 home. 
**IDE:** Visual studio 2015 
**CUDA toolkit:** 8.0.61 
**NVIDIA GPU:** GeForce GTX 960M 
**NVIDIA GPU driver:** ver 381.65 (latest) 
**Compute Capability:** 5.0 (Maxwell) 
**Unified Memory support:** is supported. 
**Intel integrated gpu:** Intel HD graphics 4600

---

### Code Sample:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TEST AREA:
// -- INCLUDE: 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Cuda Libs: ( Device Side ):
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

// Std C++ Libs:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
///////////





/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TEST AREA:
// -- NAMESPACE:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;
///////////





/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TEST AREA:
// -- START POINT:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() {

    // Set cuda Device:
    if (cudaSetDevice(0) != cudaSuccess)
        cout << "ERROR: cudaSetDevice(***)" << endl;

    // Array:
    unsigned int size = 1000;
    double * d_ptr = nullptr;

    // Allocate unified memory:
    if (cudaMallocManaged(&d_ptr, size * sizeof(double), cudaMemAttachGlobal) != cudaSuccess)
        cout << "ERROR: cudaMallocManaged(***)" << endl;

    if (cudaDeviceSynchronize() != cudaSuccess)
        cout << "ERROR: cudaDeviceSynchronize(***)" << endl;

    // Prefetch:
    if(cudaMemPrefetchAsync(d_ptr, size * sizeof(double), 0) != cudaSuccess)
        cout << "ERROR: cudaMemPrefetchAsync(***)" << endl;

    // Exit:
    getchar();
}
///////////
```

Comment: the documentation says the device must have the cudaDevAttrConcurrentManagedAccess attribute be non-zero. Have you checked that?

Comment: Well I have now and it says that I don't have a supoort for this: `(cudaDeviceProp)devProp.concurrentManagedAccess == 0`. But from what I understand this is a feature that was introduced for `compute capability == 6.0` (Pascal) and `cudaMemPrefetchAsync(***)` was first introduced for devices with `compute capability == 3.0` (Kepler). Therefore I still should be able to use it even though i am just `5.0`

Comment: @talonmies  Could you be so kind and point me to the documentation page where you find it?

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8dc9199943d421bc8bc7f473df12e42

Comment: Thank you. You were right, I was wrong. My GPU does not support this feature. I can still use unified memory but without `cudaMemPrefetchAsync(***)`.

Comment: please add a short answer to your question

Comment: This api call is for pascal GPUs.  You don't have a pascal GPU, and the call would be redundant anyway because [pre-pascal UM will automatically migrate managed data to the GPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782746/why-is-nvidia-pascal-gpus-slow-on-running-cuda-kernels-when-using-cudamallocmana/40011988#40011988) at kernel launch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank to [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) I have realized that my GPU does not support `prefetch` feature. In order to be able to use `cudaMemPrefetchAsync(***)` gpu must have non-zero value in `(cudaDeviceProp)deviceProp.concurrentManagedAccess`.

See more [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8dc9199943d421bc8bc7f473df12e42).

Comment: Please remember to come back in a couple of days and accept this answer so your question falls off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag