# Cuda Unified memory vs cudaMalloc

Tags: cuda, benchmarking, nvidia, unified-memory

I am trying to do some benchmarking to ensure using CUDA's Unified Memory(UM) approach will not hurt us wrt performance.

I am performing an FFT. One way i use UM, one way i use the cudaMalloc

I compare the results afterwards and they all match up (which is good).

however, the timing i'm getting for the UM approach is ~.5ms vs the cudaMalloc way of ~.04 (after performing the run multiple times an averaging)

I am using Event records to do the timing. I have one right before and after the cufftExecC2C call.

Furthermore, I added two more event records to measure the time before any memory transfer to the device, and after using the data once i get it back from the device.

when doing this, i see the UM approach take ~1.6ms and the cudaMalloc approach taking ~.7.

Below is a snippet of code that does the UM approach:

```
cufftHandle plan;
cufftPlan1d(&plan, dataSize, CUFFT_C2C, 1);

cudaMallocManaged(&inData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex));
cudaMallocManaged(&outData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex));

cudaEvent_t start_before_memHtoD, start_kernel, stop_kernel,
                stop_after_memDtoH;
cudaEventCreate(&start_kernel);
cudaEventCreate(&start_before_memHtoD);
cudaEventCreate(&stop_kernel);
cudaEventCreate(&stop_after_memDtoH);

setupWave(dataSize, inData);

cudaEventRecord(start_before_memHtoD);
cudaMemPrefetchAsync(inData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex), 1);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaEventRecord(start_kernel);

cufftExecC2C(plan, inData, outData, CUFFT_FORWARD);

cudaEventRecord(stop_kernel);

cudaEventSynchronize(stop_kernel);

float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        sum += outData[i].x + outData[i].y;
}
cudaEventRecord(stop_after_memDtoH);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop_after_memDtoH);

std::cout << "sum for UM is " << sum << std::endl;

float umTime = 0;
float overallUmTime = 0;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&umTime, start_kernel, stop_kernel);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&overallUmTime, start_before_memHtoD,
                stop_after_memDtoH);

resultString_um += std::to_string(dataSize) + " samples took "
                + std::to_string(umTime) + "ms,  Overall: "
                + std::to_string(overallUmTime) + "\n";

cudaFree(outData);
cudaFree(inData);
cudaEventDestroy(start_kernel);
cudaEventDestroy(stop_kernel);

cudaEventDestroy(start_before_memHtoD);
cudaEventDestroy(stop_after_memDtoH);

cufftDestroy(plan);
```

The following is for the cudaMalloc approach

```
cufftComplex *d_inData;
cufftComplex *d_outData;
inData = (cufftComplex*) (malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex) * dataSize));
outData = (cufftComplex*) (malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex) * dataSize));
cudaMalloc((void**) (&d_inData), dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex));
cudaMalloc((void**) (&d_outData), dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex));
cufftHandle plan;
cufftPlan1d(&plan, dataSize, CUFFT_C2C, 1);

cudaEvent_t start_before_memHtoD, start_kernel, stop_kernel,
                stop_after_memDtoH;
cudaEventCreate(&start_kernel);
cudaEventCreate(&start_before_memHtoD);
cudaEventCreate(&stop_kernel);
cudaEventCreate(&stop_after_memDtoH);

setupWave(dataSize, inData);

cudaEventRecord(start_before_memHtoD);
cudaMemcpy(d_inData, inData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex),
                                        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaEventRecord(start_kernel);

cufftExecC2C(plan, d_inData, d_outData, CUFFT_FORWARD);

cudaEventRecord(stop_kernel);

cudaEventSynchronize(stop_kernel);

cudaMemcpy(outData, d_outData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex),
                cudaMemcpyDefault);
cudaEventRecord(stop_after_memDtoH);

float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        sum += outData[i].x + outData[i].y;
}
cudaEventRecord(stop_after_memDtoH);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop_after_memDtoH);

std::cout << "sum for UM is " << sum << std::endl;

float umTime = 0;
float overallUmTime = 0;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&umTime, start_kernel, stop_kernel);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&overallUmTime, start_before_memHtoD,
                stop_after_memDtoH);

resultString_um += std::to_string(dataSize) + " samples took "
                + std::to_string(umTime) + "ms,  Overall: "
                + std::to_string(overallUmTime) + "\n";

cudaFree(outData);
cudaFree(inData);
cudaFree(d_outData);
cudaFree(d_inData);
cudaEventDestroy(start_kernel);
cudaEventDestroy(stop_kernel);

cudaEventDestroy(start_before_memHtoD);
cudaEventDestroy(stop_after_memDtoH);

cufftDestroy(plan);
```

Is there something else I could be doing when using the unified memory approach to speed it up?  I expected UM to be slower, but not by this much.

We are using the P100 on redhat 7.3 with Cuda 9

Comment: It would be nice if you would provide a [mcve]. Others can then easily try your code and provide better help.

Comment: Unified memory is slow. There is no way around that

Comment: For questions about UM, it is pretty much necessary to provide the operating system, the CUDA version, and the GPU you are running on, to provide crisp answers.  For some combinations, you will be in a demand-paged regime, and that is slower than `cudaMalloc` if you migrate a lot of data that way.  The usual advice there is to properly use [`cudaMemPrefetchAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782746/why-is-nvidia-pascal-gpus-slow-on-running-cuda-kernels-when-using-cudamallocmana/40011988#40011988) (<-click and read).

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  I updated the question to add more information.
i have tried using cudaMemPrefetchAsync, and then a stream synchronize (as well as device synchronize), then start the timing for the kernal call, but it still results in a much longer time to process.  i would have expected the use of cudaMemPrefetchAsync and cudaMemCopy would result in simular kernel execution times

Comment: I suggest you provide a complete code someone else could test.  Also, you may need to do a prefetch on `outData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your posted code is that you are not doing a `cudaMemPrefetchAsync` on the *output* data from the FFT.  According to my testing, this makes a significant difference.  There were a few other problems with your code, for example we do not call `cudaFree` on a pointer allocated with `malloc`.

Here's a complete code built around what you have shown.  When I run this on CentOS7.4, CUDA 9.1, Tesla P100, I get comparable times for the FFT performed in the managed memory case (3.52ms) vs.  the FFT performed in the non-managed memory case (3.45ms):

```
$ cat t43.cu
#include <cufft.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//using namespace std;
const int dataSize  = 1048576*32;
void setupWave(const int ds, cufftComplex *d){
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++){
    d[i].x = 1.0f;
    d[i].y = 0.0f;}
}
int main(){

cufftComplex *inData, *outData;

cufftHandle plan;
cufftPlan1d(&plan, dataSize, CUFFT_C2C, 1);

cudaMallocManaged(&inData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex));
cudaMallocManaged(&outData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex));

cudaEvent_t start_before_memHtoD, start_kernel, stop_kernel,
                stop_after_memDtoH;
cudaEventCreate(&start_kernel);
cudaEventCreate(&start_before_memHtoD);
cudaEventCreate(&stop_kernel);
cudaEventCreate(&stop_after_memDtoH);

setupWave(dataSize, inData);

cudaEventRecord(start_before_memHtoD);
cudaMemPrefetchAsync(inData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex), 0);
cudaMemPrefetchAsync(outData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex), 0);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaEventRecord(start_kernel);

cufftExecC2C(plan, inData, outData, CUFFT_FORWARD);

cudaEventRecord(stop_kernel);

cudaEventSynchronize(stop_kernel);

float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        sum += outData[i].x + outData[i].y;
}
cudaEventRecord(stop_after_memDtoH);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop_after_memDtoH);

std::cout << "sum for UM is " << sum << std::endl;

float umTime = 0;
float overallUmTime = 0;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&umTime, start_kernel, stop_kernel);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&overallUmTime, start_before_memHtoD,
                stop_after_memDtoH);

std::string resultString_um = std::to_string(dataSize) + " samples took " + std::to_string(umTime) + "ms,  Overall: " + std::to_string(overallUmTime) + "\n";

std::cout << resultString_um;
cudaEventDestroy(start_kernel);
cudaEventDestroy(stop_kernel);
cudaFree(inData);
cudaFree(outData);
cudaEventDestroy(start_before_memHtoD);
cudaEventDestroy(stop_after_memDtoH);

cufftDestroy(plan);



cufftComplex *d_inData;
cufftComplex *d_outData;
inData = (cufftComplex*) (malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex) * dataSize));
outData = (cufftComplex*) (malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex) * dataSize));
cudaMalloc((void**) (&d_inData), dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex));
cudaMalloc((void**) (&d_outData), dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex));
//cufftHandle plan;
cufftPlan1d(&plan, dataSize, CUFFT_C2C, 1);

//cudaEvent_t start_before_memHtoD, start_kernel, stop_kernel,
//                stop_after_memDtoH;
cudaEventCreate(&start_kernel);
cudaEventCreate(&start_before_memHtoD);
cudaEventCreate(&stop_kernel);
cudaEventCreate(&stop_after_memDtoH);

setupWave(dataSize, inData);

cudaEventRecord(start_before_memHtoD);
cudaMemcpy(d_inData, inData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex),
                                        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaEventRecord(start_kernel);

cufftExecC2C(plan, d_inData, d_outData, CUFFT_FORWARD);

cudaEventRecord(stop_kernel);

cudaEventSynchronize(stop_kernel);

cudaMemcpy(outData, d_outData, dataSize * sizeof(cufftComplex),
                cudaMemcpyDefault);

 sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        sum += outData[i].x + outData[i].y;
}
cudaEventRecord(stop_after_memDtoH);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop_after_memDtoH);

std::cout << "sum for non-UM is " << sum << std::endl;

//float umTime = 0;
//float overallUmTime = 0;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&umTime, start_kernel, stop_kernel);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&overallUmTime, start_before_memHtoD,
                stop_after_memDtoH);

resultString_um = std::to_string(dataSize) + " samples took "
                + std::to_string(umTime) + "ms,  Overall: "
                + std::to_string(overallUmTime) + "\n";
std::cout << resultString_um;
free(outData);
free(inData);
cudaFree(d_outData);
cudaFree(d_inData);
cudaEventDestroy(start_kernel);
cudaEventDestroy(stop_kernel);

cudaEventDestroy(start_before_memHtoD);
cudaEventDestroy(stop_after_memDtoH);

cufftDestroy(plan);

}
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_60 -o t43 t43.cu -lcufft
$ ./t43
sum for UM is 3.35544e+07
33554432 samples took 3.520640ms,  Overall: 221.909988
sum for non-UM is 3.35544e+07
33554432 samples took 3.456160ms,  Overall: 278.099426
$
```

Comment: Thank you. this helped a lot.  One question i have is why do we have to transfer the out data down before a calculation? Is there a way to tell the api when calling cudaMallocManaged that it should allocate data on the GPU?  to me it is counterintuitive to transfer down output data? also seems like a waste of time.

Comment: When the cufft GPU code wants to write the output data, it will need to "touch" the memory pages where the output data is stored. If you use `cudaMemPrefetchAsync` to pre-populate those pages, it will mean that those pages are resident on the GPU. If you don't those pages won't be resident, and when the cufft kernel code is touching those pages, it will generate page faults to move the pages and make them resident. This page faulting process is slower/less efficient than just moving the pages en-masse.  This is true whether the code is touching the pages for reading (input) or writing (output)